# Cannot create Function MySQL syntax errors

Tags: mysql

I cannot seem to get this working properly, its always a different error I am getting. Any suggestions are appreciated at this point...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`localhost` FUNCTION `output_date`(in_date DATE) RETURNS DATE 
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN 
    DECLARE date_format_index INT;
    DECLARE date_format_string VARCHAR;

    SELECT s.output_date_format INTO date_format_index FROM config s 
    SET date_format_string = ( CASE date_format_index WHEN 2 THEN '%d-%m-%Y' WHEN 3 THEN '%m-%d-%Y' ELSE '%Y-%m-%d' END );

    RETURN in_date 
END
```

I am using DELIMITER $$ when attempting to process this function.

The current error is ...

```
Error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; SELECT s.output_date_format INTO date_format_index FROM system_config s SET d'
```

My environment is MyEclipse, newest version.
The MySQL version I have is 5.2.

Comment: A different error each time is suspect. Can you post some examples? What  MySQL client are you using to create it? Some would require you to define a temporarily different delimiter than `;` to allow the internally ;-terminated statements to be parsed correctly.

Comment: I am using "DELIMITER $$" when attempting to compile. I'll post some of the errors in a moment. As well as my environment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some semi-colons and a problem with varchar, try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`localhost` FUNCTION `output_date`(in_date DATE) RETURNS DATE 
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN 
    DECLARE date_format_index INT;
    DECLARE date_format_string VARCHAR(100);  -- obviously change the size

    SELECT s.output_date_format INTO date_format_index FROM config s;
    SET date_format_string = ( CASE date_format_index WHEN 2 THEN '%d-%m-%Y' WHEN 3 THEN '%m-%d-%Y' ELSE '%Y-%m-%d' END );

    RETURN in_date;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It runs on my box.